# React facebook share not working on open graph meta tags with server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, facebook-opengraph, react-helmet

I have tried to share images on facebook with React. I have dynamically added og:image tags using react-helmet npm and also pre-rendered the build using react-snapshot. while view the source the og:image URL's are present but when I try to share the image it won't share.

if I provide the static og:image URL in index.html the facebook works as expected. I have tried the pre-render with react-snapshot and add meta tags

```
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

fbshare1 = () => {
    window.open(
        'https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href), 
        'facebook-share-dialog', 
        'width=626,height=436'); 
        return false;
}

<Helmet>
  <title>About us Title</title>
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://little-parrot-19.localtunnel.me" />
        <meta property="og:title"  content="Welcome to Passup" />
        <meta property="og:description"  content="A URL with no session id or extraneous parameters. All shares on Facebook will use this as the identifying URL for this article." />
        <meta property="og:image"  content="https://external-preview.redd.it/QB5Nv2dee5NmtpgFOxdjBrfp4MitMx_7OPoYVOLceVk.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=1fb548e43b8e5fe9b2fd7ba26af6da4221efcddb" />
        <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" /> 
        <meta property="og:type"   content="Free Web" />
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="12345678900" />   
        <meta property="article:author" content="Passup" />   
        <meta property="article:publisher" content="Passup trioangle" />   
        <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://external-preview.redd.it/QB5Nv2dee5NmtpgFOxdjBrfp4MitMx_7OPoYVOLceVk.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=1fb548e43b8e5fe9b2fd7ba26af6da4221efcddb" />
        <meta property="og:image:width" content="400" /> 
        <meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
</Helmet>

<a href="#" onClick={this.fbshare1}> Share on Facebook without sharer fb2 </a>
```

on the otherhand my server side rendering looks like this with express

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import React from 'react';
import express from 'express';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import {StaticRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import App from '../src/App';


const PORT = 3006;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('./build'));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<StaticRouter location= 
{req.url}><App /></StaticRouter>);

const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
const indexFile = path.resolve('./build/index.html');  
fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
if (err) {      
  return res.status(500).send('Oops, better luck next time!');
}
res.send(formatHTML(app, helmet));
});
});
const formatHTML = (appStr, helmet)  => {
 return `
 <!doctype html>
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" 
      ${helmet.htmlAttributes.toString()}>
    <head>
        ${helmet.title.toString()}
        ${helmet.meta.toString()}
        ${helmet.link.toString()}
    </head>
    <body ${helmet.bodyAttributes.toString()}>
        <div id="app">
            ${appStr}                
        </div>
    </body>       
</html>
`
}
app.listen(PORT, () => {
 console.log(` Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check  [next framework](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-document). It have server side rendering for react. It is very easy to setup and use it. They have pretty good documentation. Read the documentation and see how _document.js works in this framework it will do the job. Good luck :)

More info about the next server side rendering [here](https://nextjs.org/features/server-side-rendering)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [react-helmet-async](https://github.com/staylor/react-helmet-async), which was a fork of react-helmet developed to solve such issues.

Just don't forget to wrap your application inside a `HelmetProvider` which is used to manage Helmet's state using React's context API.

You'll need react 16+ to use this package.

Comment: Tried this one out, but it didn´t work for me. Anyone has another soluction for og meta tags to work (preview link on social medias) using server side rendering without Next.JS?

Comment: Damn! React is so good but when it comes to SEO things its very much frustrating.